# Chamisha Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

165 were the adonim of the mishkan.

96 for the mishkan's support (40+40+16)

4 for the paroches

5 for the opening of the mishkan

60 around the chatzer (20+20+10+3+3+4)

Answer (score 4):

> In the early years of World War II,
>   Ecuador still admitted a certain
>   amount of immigrants, and in 1939,
>   when several South American countries
>   refused to accept the **165** Jewish
>   refugees from Germany aboard the ship
>   "Koenigstein," Ecuador granted them
>   entry permits.

http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/vjw/Ecuador.html

Comment: Yey Ecuador!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

*Yishmael* would have been 165 when *Yosef* was born.

Answer (score 3):

165 YEARS that are MISsing from the CALenDAR. ([Approximately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_years_%28Jewish_calendar%29))

Comment: You can't answer these years later! Otherwise you could go find cool numbers and add them to the corresponding number. That defeats the purpose of this challenge! :)

Comment: @l' I've only been on this site since 278 and we all know the lower numbers are more fun. I have to lose out on all the fun?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to msh210 answer:

Gen 12:17
**וַיְנַגַּ֨ע יְהוָ֧ה** ׀ אֶת־פַּרְעֹ֛ה נְגָעִ֥ים גְּדֹלִ֖ים וְאֶת־בֵּית֑וֹ עַל־דְּבַ֥ר שָׂרַ֖י אֵ֥שֶׁת אַבְרָֽם׃
But the LORD afflicted Pharaoh and his household with mighty plagues on account of Sarai, the wife of Abram.

**165 = וַיְנַגַּ֨ע** **יְהוָ֧ה**

Encyclopedia of Biblical Personalities p.236; Sefer Hayashar, Vayeishev: Ishmaelites hit Yoseph crying for home while riding on a camel. They dismounted. Gd caused the skin of his afflictors to dry.

Ibid.; Bereshis Rabbah 84:22 - Rav Huna answered 5 bills of sale were for Yoseph: The Ishmaelites bought and sold him. And Potiphar (in Egypt).