# Rishonim saying Ester took place during the second bayis

Tags: sources-mekorot, time, megillat-esther, beis-hamikdash

[Elsewhere on this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34125), [avi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/u/597) cited sources to the effect that, contrary to the *Bavli* (*M'gila*), the events recounted in the book of *Ester* took place *after* the second *bes hamikdash* was built. Do any *rishonim* (or earlier Judaism sources) say as much, thus lending credibility to the claim? (A number of *rishonim*, in their commentaries on *Nach*, did not hesitate to argue with the *Bavli*'s reading of *Nach*.) I seek not sources who merely could be interpreted as implying as much (after all, one could say the *p'sukim* themselves imply as much), but sources who actually say so.

Comment: Why do rishonim affect believability here? They were working with less than we have to determine the history.

Comment: @DoubleAA _Rishonim_ had a better _m'sora_ than we do about what took place when: they were closer to the events. Also, they were holier than we, so I trust their reading of _Tanach_ more than I trust later persons' reading of it, especially where such contradicts the (holier yet) _Bavli_.

Comment: ... To be honest, I wouldn't mind early _acharonim_ as answers to the question, but I figured "_rishonim_" is a (slightly) easier-to-define category than "_rishonim_ and early _acharonim_", so I left it at that.

Comment: Holiness is a pretty unfit tool for determining history. How does it help? Were they receiving prophecy? Do you have any evidence for that? I trust that given a history they could derive better messages from the stories, I guess. I'm not sure what mesora you are talking about here. I'm not aware of any such mesora nor do I know of any evidence for it. Do you think there were details about the Persian kings passed down secretly and not recorded till late rishonim? What evidence do you have for that claim? What's the incentive for them to do that?

Comment: Holiness is a pretty fit tool for interpreting _Tanach_, and I don't think it's unlikely that _rishonim_ had a _m'sora_, when they learned _Ester_, that "this took place before|after the _binyan bayis sheni_" (nothing necessarily to do with Persian kings directly).

Comment: I don't see how your first statement contradicts me as there is plenty of interpreting to be done without knowing the history at all. I also don't think you appreciate just how connected Persian history is to dating events in Esther/Ezra. If you don't know the relevant Persian history, there's no way you can be expected to understand the verses accurately. It's not like they were written to teach us Persian history.

Comment: Very, very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35457

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly held opinion is that the story of Esther took place after the foundation of the 2nd Beis HaMikdash was built, but before the building was completed. (See Artscroll on Ezra, among others; Medrash Esther Rabba; etc.) The building process was halted by royal edict in the middle of the construction. The exact timeline is discussed in depth by the commentaries on Ezra, where the text itself gives many details of the sequence of events.

Therefore, one could correctly say that the story of Purim took place after the [start of the] building of the 2nd Beis HaMikdash, before the [end of the] building of the 2nd Beis HaMikdash, or during the building of the 2nd Beis HaMikdash. It's just a matter of semantics.

Comment: "The accepted opinion" What does that even mean?

Comment: -1 avi's first source by [Rabbi Chaim (Howard) Jachter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Jachter) states "even though the events of Megillat Ester occurred in 482 B.C.E., 478 B.C.E., and 473 B.C.E., long after Cyrus permitted Jews to return to Eretz Yisrael (539 B.C.E.) and the Beit Hamikdash was completed (515 B.C.E.)."

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for the correction. I removed the incorrect section.

Comment: But what is left in this post then? msh210 for some unclear reason want's to know if anyone from a certain limited time period held that view. Can you provide a source to any such example?

Comment: @DoubleAA Until we have a better answer, this serves the purpose of disambiguation by clarifying exactly what is being discussed, which is permitted according to the Mi Yodeya Meta. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/is-it-ok-to-post-extensive-comments-as-answers

Comment: This doesn't qualify under that post at least because it doesn't acknowledge it is not an answer. I'm also not really clear how this material is so helpful as it discusses opinion specifically excluded by the op.

Comment: @LN6595, one score-two answer on Meta is ***not*** the same as the community agreeing on something.

Comment: So go ahead and let's figure out what the community agrees. But absent a clear consensus otherwise, the approach Mike takes seems logical to me.

Comment: Please see isaac's answer there then please [edit] your post to indicate how it "at least provide[s] information that could be helpful toward getting an answer to the question". Right now i dont see how this qualifies.

Comment: @LN6595 Again, there is clear consensus there in the form of Isaac's answer. Please edit to bring this into line, or it is likely to be deleted.