# Responses to Dr. Chaim S. Heifetz's timeline of Persian History

Tags: history

Dr. Chaim S. Heifetz has been quoted in a few places as revising the history timeline which if correct would greatly impact Jewish history from the Persian empire and on.

See [here](http://www.simpletoremember.com/other/History166.htm)

And in [this download](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=B4eSVfOeJIqXyATsm5SwDg&url=http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%25203%2520Epstein.pdf&ved=0CB4QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNGlLtxJsS89oUGh4xy_QTB1lYnC2g&sig2=7fjSoiKf8GB4jppuKCXbwA)

In note #15 of that pdf: (the link is not working)
  "A critique of Heifetz can be 
found [here](http://www.talkreason.org/articles/fixing1.cfm). Aaronson concedes 
that Heifetz admits that “his is a work in progress” and “more work needs to be done.” To our knowledge, in the intervening 15 years since 
these articles were published, there has been no further evidence forthcoming to support Heifetz’s work."

Has Heifetz's theory been discussed  by any noted Rabbis or religious leaders?

Comment: http://www.herzog.ac.il/index.php/component/content/article/17-/702-

Comment: Nice! I couldn't find anything! Ty.

Comment: I think there's a longer version of R Medan's critiqe somewhere. Essentially [Cheifetz's work](http://www.herzog.ac.il/tvunot/fulltext/mega14_hefetz.pdf) is highly speculative. Most other religious leaders don't ever mention this issue because it's awkward. Most people can understand how "science" and "Torah" have different opinions about creation, but to understand the depth of the contradiction here involves a little more background, so few rabbis ask and those that do generally are content with "science is stupid" as an answer.

Comment: True. And the one that did (Rabbi Schwab) supposedly got bullied about it.

Comment: "the one that did" Literally. The only response you can find besides "science is stupid" is "R Schwab wrote about it and figured it out, I think".

Comment: Is this [on-topic](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1474)? (cc @DoubleAA )

Comment: @msh210 Rabbinic responses to a theory about how to understand Tanakh? What's the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't follow the links from the question, and nothing in the text of the question itself indicates that _Tanach_ is under discussion.

Comment: @msh210 It's about persian history and understanding the [missing years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_years_(Jewish_calendar)) which has plenty of [applications to tanakh](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34241/759)

Comment: @DoubleAA I see nothing in the question that indicates as much.