# The curse of King Darius

Tags: history, midrash, beis-hamikdash, purim

In sefer [Ezra 6:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.6.11?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%98%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%9D%20%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%87%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%90%D6%B1%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%A9%D7%81%20%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B5%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%B0%D7%92%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%90%20%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B0%D7%A1%D6%B7%D7%97%20%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A2%20%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%9F%D6%BE%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%94%D6%BC%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%96%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A3%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%97%D6%B5%D7%90%20%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%94%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%91%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%94%D6%BC%20%D7%A0%D6%B0%D7%95%D6%B8%D7%9C%D7%95%D6%BC%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%AA%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%91%D6%B5%D7%93%20%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%94) it tells us that King Darius decreed that anyone who attempted to disrupt the resumed construction of the beis hamikdash would have a beam removed from their home and they would be killed with it.

This is very similar to what had occurred to Haman and his sons about whom it says that they orchestrated the "stop work order" on the rebuilding of the second beis hamikdash which was issued by Achashverosh.

The [Midrash Panim Acheirim](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Aggadah_on_Esther%2C_Midrash_Panim_Acherim%2C_Version_II.5.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%93%20%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%2C%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%2C%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%20(%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A9%20%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90)%20%5B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A9%20%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90%5D%20%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%A2%20%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%94) as well as the [Yalkut Shemoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1056.21?lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%93%20%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A9%20%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%97%20%D7%90%D7%A2%20%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%27%2C) seem to say that Haman and his sons were killed in that manner because of this warning issued by Darius.

My question is, how could it be that Haman and sons were punished in a manner that was described after their death. Since Darius is known to be the son of Esther (see Vayikra Rabbah) and therefore would have been king many years after Haman's pdeath.

Comment: Two midrashim don't have to agree with each other. The simplest answer is thus "The Midrash Panim Acheirim as well as the Yalkut Shemoni" don't agree with "Vayikra Rabbah" about the order of events.

Comment: @DoubleAA Meaning to say that there are opinions who believe that darius ruled before achashverosh? I think that would throw a lot f things off, considering that it was during darius reign that the beis hamikdash was completed.

Comment: Note as well that there plausibly were (and there is historical evidence for) multiple different kings named Darius.

Comment: Here's a good example: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117000/ chain together three midrashim (Darius=Artaxerxes, Artaxerxes= Ahasuerus, and Ahasuerus fathered Darius) and you'll find someone is his own son!

Comment: @DoubleAA oh, interesting. thank you.

Comment: @DoubleAA the chiddush here would be that Purim was during Bayis Sheini - Haman would be post the curse, under a different king under whom construction began & ended on. Definitely not the traditional view, even accounting for multiple Dariuses (Dari'i?) though I believe there are academics who argue for it...

Comment: @TheTargum I can't think of any offhand, but "anachronistic" drashos are made sometimes  The wording of the Yalkut you quote however implies lije you understood it.